# dividir texto separado por coma a columnas separadas

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito colocar datos separados por coma, creando un campo al lado; por ejemplo, tengo esta tabla que escribe varios valores de texto, separado por coma, en un mismo campo.

```
    SELECT
         ID,
            Condicion

    FROM extintores


      ID   |         Condicion         |
    |----------------------------------
    |1|    |apagado,prendido,dañado,etc|
    |2|    | expuesto,interior,exterior|
```

Necesito poder ver los datos de esta manera

```
| num |    Cond1 |    Cond2 |    Cond3 | Cond34 |
|-----|----------|----------|----------|--------|
|   4 |  apagado | prendido |   dañado |    etc |
|   3 | expuesto | interior | exterior | (null) |
```

Comment: Saludos. Dale mejor presentación; en lo personal como que no se aprecia bien lo que tienes y lo que deseas obtener.

Comment: Puedes separar los datos después de leerlos, dependiendo del lenguaje que estés usando, por ejemplo, en php sería: `$condicion = explode(',', $row['Condicion'])`. Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega más información y el código que has intentado para separar los datos.

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta! pero solo necesitaria hacerlo en una consulta mysql tengo un campo que se llama condición y dentro contiene estos datos ejemplo(a, b, c) yo quiero que a, b, c me figueren separados  como cuando haces un concat que te crea el campo personalizado con el dato que quieras

Comment: ahi modifique como quiero que sea vea estuvieron muy cerca de lo que quería trasnmitir. solo faltaría el total de cada dato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo, con un poco de trabajo y usando `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` para ir recortando cada bloque entre los delimitadores.

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table ejemplo(Condicion varchar(255));

insert into ejemplo (Condicion) values('apagado,prendido,dañado,etc');
insert into ejemplo (Condicion) values('expuesto,interior,exterior');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
    @num := 1 + LENGTH(Condicion) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Condicion, ',', ''))              AS num,
    IF(@num > 1, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Condicion, ',', 1), NULL)                           AS Cond1,
    IF(@num > 1, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Condicion, ',', 2), ',', -1), NULL) AS Cond2,
    IF(@num > 2, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Condicion, ',', 3), ',', -1), NULL) AS Cond3,
    IF(@num > 3, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Condicion, ',', 4), ',', -1), NULL) AS Cond34
    from ejemplo
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eda84a/6/0)**:

```
| num |    Cond1 |    Cond2 |    Cond3 | Cond34 |
|-----|----------|----------|----------|--------|
|   4 |  apagado | prendido |   dañado |    etc |
|   3 | expuesto | interior | exterior | (null) |
```

Comment: excelente era lo que estaba buscando muchas gracias!!!!!!!!!

Comment: He usado tu formula y estoy teniendo un inconveniente, como condición yo estoy usando un group_concat y el problema que me está trayendo es que si detecta dos comas me las separa en el registro posterior (que no tiene comas). No se si hay forma de solucionarlo. Te adjunto imagen del resultado y del codigo. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjXzG.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbUAk.png

Comment: @Gonzalo,  publica un pregunta, no hay forma de responderte sino. Saludos.