# Separar nombre y apellidos en sql con select, locate y substring

Tags: sql, select

Con las funciones `select`, `substring`, `locate` y a partir de esta tabla:

| nombre_completo |
| --- |
| Itzel Ramírez González |
| Joshua Davy Castillo |
| Marisol Flores Castro |
| Sofía Pejcovich |

Generar la siguiente tabla:

| nombre_completo | nombre | primer_apellido | segundo_apellido |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Itzel Ramírez González | Itzel | Ramírez | González |
| Joshua Davy Castillo | Joshua | Davy | Castillo |
| Marisol Flores Castro | Marisol | Flores | Castro |
| Sofía Pejcovich | Sofía | Pejcovich |  |

Hice este código, pero cuando no se tiene un segundo apellido no funciona.

```
SELECT nombre_completo, 
SUBSTRING(nombre_completo, 1, LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo) - 1) AS nombre,
SUBSTRING(nombre_completo, LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo) + 1, LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo, LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo) + 1) - LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo) - 1) AS primer_apellido,
SUBSTRING(nombre_completo, LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo, LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo) + 1) + 1) AS segundo_apellido FROM datos_alumno;
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el motor de `SQL` y la versión que usas.

Comment: Tal vez [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/368745/dividir-texto-separado-por-coma-a-columnas-separadas/369181#369181) te puede ayudar.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa cuando tiene más de un nombre? ¿Cuando son apellidos compuestos? ¿Qué pasa si alguien uso un formato `apellidos, nombres`? Si es un ejercicio, se puede hacer con datos limitados, pero para un caso de la vida real es demasiado complicado y necesita revisión manual para confirmar que todos los datos son correctos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución, segundo_apellidoV2 es funcional con 1 o 2 apellidos.
También simplifique un poco el substring del primer apellido.

```
SELECT nombre_completo,
SUBSTRING(nombre_completo, 1, LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo) - 1) AS nombre,
SUBSTRING(nombre_completo, LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo) + 1, LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo) + 1 ) AS primer_apellido,
SUBSTRING(nombre_completo,LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo, LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo) +1)) AS segundo_apellido;
```

edit: Cambiados datos en duro por datos dinámicos

Comment: La respuesta está bien, pero no se tiene en cuenta una cosa muy importante, que pasaria con los nombres compuestos? Se pondria el segundo nombre como primer apellido y eso no creo que sea lo que se busque

Comment: Evita usar constantes en tus ejemplos. Son ejemplos que no se pueden usar para probar otros valores.

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que al no encontrar un espacio adicional `LOCATE` regresa un cero. Al momento de restar cualquier valor, se genera una posición negativa que es inválida como longitud. Entonces, lo que necesitamos es validar si el resultado es cero para convertirlo en otro valor. En este caso, uso una combinación de las fuciones `NULLIF` y `IFNULL` para cambiar ceros por nulos y luego el nulo por otro valor.

```
SELECT nombre_completo, 
    SUBSTRING(nombre_completo, 1, LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo) - 1) AS nombre,
    SUBSTRING(nombre_completo, LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo) + 1, IFNULL( NULLIF( LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo, LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo) + 1), 0 ) - LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo) - 1, 800)) AS primer_apellido,
    SUBSTRING(nombre_completo, IFNULL( NULLIF( LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo, LOCATE(' ', nombre_completo) + 1),0),8000) + 1, 8000) AS segundo_apellido 
FROM datos_alumno;
```